# Alterar função javascript/php de form para div

Tags: php, javascript

pessoal como eu faço para alterar a função abaixo? eu quero exibir a hora em uma div.

```
 <HTML>
 <HEAD>
 <TITLE>cronometro</TITLE>

 <script language="JavaScript">
 <!--
 function showtime()
 { setTimeout("showtime();",1000);
 callerdate.setTime(callerdate.getTime()+1000);
 var hh = String(callerdate.getHours());
 var mm = String(callerdate.getMinutes());
 var ss = String(callerdate.getSeconds());
 document.clock.face.value =
 ((hh < 10) ? " " : "") + hh +
 ((mm < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + mm +
 ((ss < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + ss;

 }
 callerdate = new Date(<?php 

date_default_timezone_set('America/sao_paulo');
$brasil = date('Y,m,d,H,i,s', time());

echo $brasil;

?>);
//-->
</script>
</HEAD>
<meta name="" content="">
<body onLoad="showtime()">
<form  name="clock"><input name="face" value=""></input>
</form> 
</body>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Mas o que está errado, a função ou só não está conseguindo exibir a hora em uma div? O seu html está todo errado tbm, tem duas tags body e a tag input não tem tag de fechamento.

Comment: Bom dia  LeAndrade, apesar dos erros que já foram corrigidos está tudo funcionando normal, eu quero apenas retirar o form e o input para colocar a informação em uma div.

Comment: Mas aí então não é só apagar o form e o input e no lugar inserir a div e do mesmo jeito que chamou a função na tag body, chamar na div criada?

Comment: mas eu preciso passar valores para div(name="clock",  name="face", value=" ") como eu faço?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para isso, você precisa alterar basicamente 3 linhas. A primeira é a linha

```
 document.clock.face.value =
```

Que deve ser alterada para:

```
document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML =
```

Logo em seguida, mudar na parte do HTML as linhas:

```
<form  name="clock"><input name="face" value=""></input>
</form>
```

Para:

```
<div id="clock"></div>
```

De forma geral, seu código ficará assim:

```
 <HTML>
 <HEAD>
 <TITLE>cronometro</TITLE>

 <script language="JavaScript">
 <!--
 function showtime()
 { setTimeout("showtime();",1000);
 callerdate.setTime(callerdate.getTime()+1000);
 var hh = String(callerdate.getHours());
 var mm = String(callerdate.getMinutes());
 var ss = String(callerdate.getSeconds());
 document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = 
 ((hh < 10) ? " " : "") + hh +
 ((mm < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + mm +
 ((ss < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + ss;

 }
 callerdate = new Date(<?php 

date_default_timezone_set('America/sao_paulo');
$brasil = date('Y,m,d,H,i,s', time());

echo $brasil;

?>);
//-->
</script>
</HEAD>
<meta name="" content="">
<body onLoad="showtime()">
<div id="clock"></div> 
</body>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Obrigado David, a principio deu certo qualquer duvida eu volto aqui.

Comment: Opa. Por nada :) Tranquilo

Comment: Boa tarde David, desculpa incomodar mas eu notei que depois de 30minutos/1hora o relógio começa á atrasa você me dizer o porque?

Comment: A princípio não sei. Mas seria atrasar com relação à qual relógio? O do seu próprio computador? Ou um relógio externo?

Comment: do computador, se você colocar esse código para rodar no wampserver e deixar o navegador aberto com ele rodando você vai ver um atraso no segundos.